# How to create a list of file with dbf extension?

Tags: r, dbf

I faced a problem when creating a list of files with `.dbf` (lowercase) extension. Here is the code:

```
listdbf <- dir(pattern = "*.dbf")
```

If I run thid code nothing happens.
However when I run code with uppercase extension specification `listdbf <- dir(pattern = "*.DBF")` everything is ok.

But I definetely need to write code with lowercase extension specification.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure with out the list of files in the directory, but I suspect it maybe related to the pattern is taken as a regex, which means '.' is a wild card representing any character. You need to escape it to represent the dot/period character.  I think the pattern you really want is `pattern = "\\.dbf$"`. This will also ensure it's at the end of the name.

Comment: I did try this version, but unfortunately it doesn't work((.